# inequality of variables without knowing their sign

Tags: inequality

I would like to manipulate an inequality when the said inequality is in terms of variables and I do not know the signs of the variables.

For example, $x_1<x_2$ and I would like to divide both sides by $x_1$.

If $x_1<0 $,    $x_1<x_2 \implies  1 >\frac{x_2}{x_1} $.

If $x_1>0 $,    $x_1<x_2 \implies  1 < \frac{x_2}{x_1} $.

But, without haivng this knowledge, do I always have to split the inequality into two separate cases, as I attempt to simplify my expression?

Comment: Yes, indeed you do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. You need to consider both cases.